# How to start a tmux within bash right after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, bash, virtualenv, tmux

I have created a script to run upon reboot of an Ubuntu instance.

```
crontab -e
```

Then added this to the script:

```
@reboot /home/ubuntu/startup.sh
```

This is how the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s my_server
tmux send-keys -t my_server:0 ". /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate" C-m
tmux send-keys -t my_server:0 "cd ~/canonicaliser_api" C-m
tmux send-keys -t my_server:0 "git checkout new-schema" C-m
tmux send-keys -t my_server:0 "git pull" C-m
tmux send-keys -t my_server:0 "cd ~/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/workers" C-m
tmux send-keys -t my_server:0 "python person_worker.py" C-m
```

After reboot I do a `tmux attach` to see the results.

```
$ . /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate
cd ~/canonicaliser_api
(venv)$ (venv)$ git checkout new-schema
git pull
cd ~/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/workers
python person_worker.py
Already on 'new-schema'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/new-schema'.
... 
7 files changed, 157 insertions(+), 20 deletions(-)
(venv)$ (venv)$ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "person_worker.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import create_app, log
ImportError: No module named app
(venv)$
```

Strangely, the virtualenv seems activate and yet doesn't seem to have worked.
The environment seems also strange.  If I run the script manually (instead of reboot) and do a `tmux attach`, I see `(venv)ubuntu@ip-172-xx-xx-xxx:` instead of just `(venv)$`. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the reason.

All I had to do was to add the Python path like this:

```
tmux send-keys -t my_server:0 "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api" C-m
```

Now it works. Hope this helps somebody else with similar requirements.